# How to disable master password window on netbeans startup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, netbeans-6.9

Whenever I run netbeans 6.9.1 in my ubuntu 12.04 it asks for master password. I hate this dialog to pop-up and want to disable it. How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution appeared to be simple. A missing package was preventing Netbeans from using Gnome Keyring.

So install libgnome-keyring-dev

`sudo apt-get install libgnome-keyring-dev`